# ScriptManager to open link in new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net

In bleow code `Page` is opening in a new window. My requirement is to open it in a new tab.

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup",
      "window.open('" + strFilePath + "','_blank')", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a new tab because that's up to the browser to decide. The user can configure his browser to open a new window on a separate tab. In the latter case, your code will work.

Comment: Is there is any possible to open new tab tab using link button

Comment: @user2439934 HTML doesn't control that. The browser could not support tabs for example, or the user might not like them. You can only say: "this link opens in a new window" and the user will choose to use a tab or a window, depending on his browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to have a windows opened in a new tab, you can only display a link and have the user, right click it, etc.

Note, that clicking a link can still cause a postback on the current page.

You'll just use a redirection on your postback.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153108.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Never waste your effort controlling client environment, I have done it many times, may be disabling right click or opening in new window, and finally had to live up with client settings for my code or hack to work the way I expected it to.

In the mean time have a look at :-

[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)